# Colon modifier in macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to use the colon modifier functionality in a macro but it doesn't seem to work the same way as in a data step. An example of what I'm trying to do is shown below.

```
data _null_;
str = "hello";
if str =: "h" then put "y";
else put "n";
run;
```

The `if-statement` evaluates `TRUE` in the data step but when I apply similar logic in the macro language this no longer appears to work.

```
%let str = hello;
%put %eval(&str =: h);
```

The code above now evaluates to `FALSE`. Is there something I'm missing here or is this modifier just not available in the macro language? I know I could use `%eval(%substr(&str,1,1)=h)` but I'm more curious to find out if the `:` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `:` is not in the list of macro operators; see the [macro language reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/PDF/default/mcrolref.pdf) for more details.

Note that `=:` is also not valid in other places, such as in `PROC SQL`.  In those contexts `eqt` is the equivalent operator, but that also does not work in the macro language.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm not sure if it has to do with the SAS version, but I am able to use `=:` in a `WHERE` statement. Example: `proc print data=sashelp.class; where name=:'Al';`.

Comment: @J_Lard Hmm, guess I'm wrong about that - corrected.  Thanks.